# Javascript reg ex combination

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var cost_price = "15..00"

/*Cost price should be such that it should contain numbers and may not contain more than one dot*/

if(/^([0-9])|([.])/.test(cost_price)){

    documet.write("Correct cost price");

}
```

Now despite of two dots in the cost_price I get the hello message. What should I change in the if condition?

P.S. I have combined 2 reg ex. one checks for correctness of digits and others checks to see if the dot occurs only once.

Comment: anchor(^) represents start of the string but as I am checking for just a char it is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Why not go for

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

and hence make the last part completely optional? (the `?` specifies "*matched 0 to 1 times*")

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In case you want to allow `.15`, you can change the first `[0-9]+` (matched 1 to infinity times) to `[0-9]*` (matched 0 to infinity times).

Comment: @whiteb0x There's an absolutely awesome site called [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com). Paste a regex and it'll do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be this for your case:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cost_price = "15..00"

if (/\d+\.\d+/.test(cost_price)) {
    documet.write("Correct cost price");
} else {
    documet.write("Incorrect cost price");
}

http://regex101.com/r/cL8pP1
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Comment: This **requires** you to type decimals though. Not sure if that was OP's intention. If it is, then this regex is more correct than the other ones.

Comment: @h2ooooooo this **matches exactly** what the OP asked.

Comment: Considering it seemed that OP wanted to make an *or* statement, I'm not completely sure. I simply described it so OP could pick the one fitting best (as he's obviously not an expert in regex). It was pure info. OP never said "REQUIRES 1 dot" but rather "may not contain more than one dot".